# SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript

I am trying to log this in the console of Chromium browser

```
function.prototype.newMethod = function(name,f){
    this.prototype[name] = f;
    return this;
}
```

and I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

I don't see the issue. Can someone please help me resolve this.

Thanks!

Comment: `function.prototype` doesn't make any sense. `function` is a reserved keyword, not a type. Do you mean `Function.prototype`?

Comment: @JakeKing—"not a type" should be "not a constructor".

Comment: Oh goodness,, I don't understand how I missed that. Function is a constructor,, what a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Function.prototype.newMethod = function(name,f){
    this.prototype[name] = f;
    return this;
}
```

with a capital F since i'm assuming you're trying to make it so every instance of 'Function' has the 'newMethod' method. Not something you'd probably really want to do, but if you're just studying/trying things out go for it.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am learning more about OOJS and how JavaScript works and trying to get better understanding of constructors over all. This is an exercise to write code that will enable adding of new method to any Constructor (for the sake of understanding how things work)